# How to find Voxel Grid Coordinates in open3d library?

Tags: python, coordinates, voxel, open3d

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size=0.05)
```

In this result, how can I found the coordinates of `voxel_grid`?

Answer (score 2):

To get each one of the voxels in the VoxelGrid, you can use:

```
voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
```

Each of the voxels in the `voxels` list have a `grid_index` attribute which contains it's `[x, y, z]` index in the voxel grid.

If you want the specific coordinate for the center-point of voxel `i`, you can use

```
index = voxels[i].grid_index
center = voxel_grid.get_voxel_center_coordinate(index)
```